# Error: Undefined name 'FOLDERID_printersFolder'. When building flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

When I try building my flutter app, regardless of the platform, I run into this error, which subsquently quits the build process.

(Android)

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.1.0/lib/src/folders.dart:122:34: Error: Undefined name 'FOLDERID_printHood'.
  static String get printHood => FOLDERID_printHood;
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.1.0/lib/src/folders.dart:125:39: Error: Undefined name 'FOLDERID_printersFolder'.
  static String get printersFolder => FOLDERID_printersFolder;
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(Windows)

```
FileSystemException: Cannot create link, path = 'C:\Users\airAdmirer\projectName\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\path_provider_windows' (OS Error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
, errno = 183)
```

I've tried-

- Deleting `pubspec.lock` file, and running ``flutter pub get```
- Running `flutter clean ; flutter pub get`
- Rebuilding my project in another directory
- Deleting flutter sdk and reinstalling it

And none seemed to work. Here's my pubspec.yaml file-

```
name: test
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  hive: 
  hive_flutter:
  flame:
  get:
  fast_noise:
  image: ^3.1.3
  panorama:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  hive_generator: 
  build_runner:

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: MinecraftFont
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/minecraft_font.ttf
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages

Note: This error doesn't occur when I run a newly created flutter project with the boilerplate code.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `path_provider` package. You might not have it directly installed, but a package you installed might depend on it. In my case `hive_flutter` used it. I fixed the issue by removing the package, and initializing hive with `Hive.init(path);`.